# Retrieve attribute with max function

Tags: sql, function, entity-framework, minimax, qsqlquery

How retrieve other attribute with max function like max salary with name.
to retrieve max salary along with their name please help anyone.

Comment: Accept and upvote the answer if it solved your problem. Or else SO will keep the question open.

Answer (score 0):

If my understanding of the question is correct, you can use something like this:

```
select name, salary from table where salary = (select max(salary) from table)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   With SalaryOrder AS (
     Select name, salary, Row_Number() Over(Order By salary Desc) RN
     From table
    )
    Select /*the top clause is needed as described below*/ Top (1) *
   From SalaryOrder Where RN = 1
```

this query may return more than a record when existing people with the same salary.
To solve this you can add more orders in CTE or use Top one to pick a random record.

Answer (score 0):

`RANK()` should be an efficient way to get name where salary is `MAX`. Using `sub-query` will also get us the same result but it will take more time than `RANK()` in some cases.

**Query:**

```
SELECT name, salary
FROM
    (
     SELECT name, salary, RANK() over(ORDER BY salary DESC) AS rnk
     FROM your_table
    ) AS a
WHERE rnk=1
```

Look at the *[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=a8710e5ef3383dc2fac6e19280133db4)* with time consumption. (The time may vary for different runs)